# How to format date in html from month dd,yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: html, django, date, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to set the value to the input of type 'date', I am fetching data from the MySQL table and setting it as the value attribute of the input tag.
On the first time it doesn't work, but if set date once then it starts working i.e. input tag shows the content of the value attribute even after refreshing.

For the first time, the date is shown as Nov 12, 2021
and from second time it shows like 12-11-2021

Here is my code for view:

```
def profile(request,id):
       project=Project.objects.get(id=id)
       if request.method=='POST':
             deadline=request.post.get('deadline')
             project.deadline=deadline
             project.save()
       return render(request,'edit_project.html',{'id':id,'project':project})
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST">
<input type='date' value={{project.deadline}}>
<input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `DATE_FORMAT = 'Y-m-d'` in your settings.py. See the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#date-format).

**EDIT:**
You can also use the template [date filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-date) as so:

```
{{project.deadline|date:"Y-m-d"}}
```